# How to run AzureRM script via azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I am attempting to run an azureRM script via a devops pipeline.

I have tried all the possible powershell tasks, however I am always met with the following error:

```
New-AzureRmResource : The term 'New-AzureRmResource' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

The script is designed to add a VNET to an app service.
I am aware that AzureRM is outdated, however there is no way to do cross-regional VNet integration via Az or the az cli.

How can I run an AzureRm script via a devops pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use Microsoft Hosted Agents

Multiple ways:

1. Invoke-RestMethod - All commands are accessible as API endpoints.
2. Install-Module - Just Install AzureRM.
3. Use AzurePowerShell@3 task version - Easiest solution - See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops#error-could-not-find-the-modules--with-version--if-the-module-was-recently-installed-retry-after-restarting-the-azure-pipelines-task-agent), The newer @4 and @5 versions do not support AzureRM.

Answer (score 3):

Because Az PowerShell modules now have all the capabilities of AzureRM PowerShell modules and more, we'll retire AzureRM PowerShell modules on 29 February 2024. So you can try to use [Az.Resources module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresource?view=azps-5.5.0) instead.

For the changes between AzureRm and Az, please view this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-az-1.0.0?view=azps-5.5.0#azresources-previously-azurermresources)(Az.Resources (previously AzureRM.Resources)).

In addition, agree with Repcak. You can use AzurePowerShell@3 task or earlier, because these versions of task support AzureRm modules.

[image]

Comment: Using the Az module is not feasible for this task - The Az module for creating VNET integration does not support cross-regional VNET integration whereas the AzureRM feature does. Using AzurePowerShell@3 works.